# Must use set method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the error `You must use the "set" method to update an entry.` when I use the following method. I am using Jamie Rumbelow's MY_Model to do this.

```
$this->failed_login->insert_login_attempt($this->input->ip_address(), 
                                $post_username,
                                gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())); 

public function insert_login_attempt($user_ip_address, $username, 
                                $datetime_of_attempt)
{

    $failed_attempt = array(
        'user_ip_address' => $user_ip_address,
        'username' => $username,
        'datetime');
    $this->db->insert($failed_attempt);

}
```

Comment: Search the codebase for that message and backtrace it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$this->db->insert`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert) needs to know which table you want to insert the table into.  How does it know where to put the data if you don't give it a table? :-P

```
$failed_attempt = array(
    'user_ip_address' => $user_ip_address,
    'username' => $username,
    'datetime' => $datetime_of_attempt);

$this->db->insert('YOUR_TABLE', $failed_attempt);
```

**EDIT**: Since you are using [jamierumbelow's `MY_Model`](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model), you need to follow their docs.

```
$failed_attempt = array(
    'user_ip_address' => $user_ip_address,
    'username' => $username,
    'datetime' => $datetime_of_attempt);

$this->insert($failed_attempt);
// OR $this->failed_login->insert($failed_attempt);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it know from how using the MY_Model takes the model name and uses the plural of it to find the table name

Comment: I've never used `MY_Model`, so I have no idea.

Comment: Ok, I just looked it up, and the docs say you need to use the model's `->insert()` method, *NOT* `$this->db->insert`.

Comment: That's what I missed. Thank you.